# Distance of nearest zero of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, cauchy-integral-formula, analytic-functions

Prove that the distance of the nearest zero of the function $f(z)={\sum}_{s=0}^{\infty}\: c_nz^n$ to the point $z=0$ is not less than $\frac{r|c_0|}{M+|c_0|}$, where r is any number not exceeding the radius of convergence of the series, and $M(r)= \max\limits_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$.

I followed the hint to first establish that the function $f(z)$ has no zero in the domain where $|f(z)-c_0|<|c_0|$. The next hint is to estimate  $|f(z)-c_0|$ using Cauchy's inequality. But, I am getting $|c_0|<M$ using that inequality and unable to proceed further. Please suggest the way forward. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$g(z)=\frac{f(z)-c_0}{z}$ has the same radius of convergence as $f$. By the maximums principle, 
$$
g(z_0)< \sup_{|z|=r}|g(z)|\le \frac{M+|c_0|}{r}
$$
for all $|z_0|<r$. For the Rouché theorem to show no roots by comparing $f$ to the constant function $c_0$ we need 
$$
|f(z)-c_0|< |c_0|\quad\forall |z|=\rho
$$
or
$$
|g(z)|<\frac{|c_0|}{\rho}.
$$
This is satisfied if $\rho<r$ and
$$
\frac{M+|c_0|}{r}\le \frac{|c_0|}{\rho}
\iff
\rho\le \frac{|c_0|r}{M+|c_0|}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. You are saying that $\rho$ is the radius of any circle not enclosing a root and you establish that $\rho$ can be any number less than RHS of final inequality, implying that the nearest root is at least as farther away from origin as the RHS. One Q. though, how does strict inequality becomes $\leq$ on last step.

Comment: You get the strict inequality from the first formula and the fact that $\frac{|c_0|}{M+|c_0|}<1$ for $M\ne 0$. $M=0$ would imply $f=0$, so is excluded.

Comment: Is it possible to prove this without invoking maximum modulus principle or Rouches theorem? Was asked this question but can only rely on Taylor series, Cauchy inequality, identity theorem

Comment: You can find similar, but not as strict, bounds for the inner root radius similar to the formulas for the polynomial case. But the inclusion of $M=M(r)$ in the task only works with the Cauchy integral formula or the maximum modulus principle.